Why I'm not getting rid of this TS2322 error in Typescript?
I'm working on this React demo projects where I'm using redux. The app's logic is totally basic and is done just for practicing purpose, but an unknown error has been overwhelming me. I've defined a redux store and have used it in two components, the app works correctly and there's no warning in the browser's console, but the error in the IDE is just not going away no matter how I try to modify the code.
I'd be appreciating it if anyone could help me with this.

TS2322: Type 'Reducer<ItemState>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<ItemState, UnknownAction, Task[]>'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'ItemState | Task[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ItemState | undefined'.
Property 'tasks' is missing in type 'Task[]' but required in type 'ItemState'.


This is how the redux store is defined:
import {
  configureStore,
  createSlice,
  PayloadAction
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface Task {
  id: number,
  title: string
  description: string
  date: any
}

interface ItemState {
  tasks: Task[]   
}

interface RootState {
  tasks: ItemState
}

const saveState = (state: ItemState) => {
  const savedState = JSON.stringify(state)
  localStorage.setItem('saveFile', savedState)
}

const loadState = (): ItemState | undefined => {
  const savedState = localStorage.getItem('saveFile')
  if (savedState) {
    const parsedState = JSON.parse(savedState)
    return { tasks: parsedState || [] }
  }
  return undefined
}

const itemSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'addNew',
  initialState: {tasks: []} as ItemState,
  reducers: {
    addNewTask(state, action: PayloadAction<Task>) {
      state.tasks.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

const mainStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: itemSlice.reducer
  },
  preloadedState: loadState()
})

mainStore.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(mainStore.getState().tasks)
})

export default mainStore;
export type { RootState }
export const reduxActions = itemSlice.actions
export { itemSlice }

I don't think that it's necessary to also share the store usages in other components, as the error occurred when I added the local storage (specifically loadState() function).

Issue
The issue is that saveState persist only the state.tasks state, but preloadedState expects an entire state object, e.g. RootState type, but loadState only returns a state.tasks ItemState type object.
Solution Suggestion

Persist the entire state:
const saveState = (state: RootState) => { // <-- entire state
  const savedState = JSON.stringify(state);
  localStorage.setItem("saveFile", savedState);
};

const loadState = (): RootState | undefined => {
  const savedState = localStorage.getItem("saveFile");
  if (savedState) {
    return JSON.parse(savedState); // <-- entire state
  }
  return undefined;
};

const mainStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: itemSlice.reducer,
  },
  preloadedState: loadState(), // <-- entire state
});

mainStore.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(mainStore.getState()); // <-- entire state
});


Fix the logic to load only the partial state.tasks state:
const saveState = (state: ItemState) => { // <-- state.tasks
  const savedState = JSON.stringify(state);
  localStorage.setItem("saveFile", savedState);
};

const loadState = (): RootState | undefined => {
  const savedState = localStorage.getItem("saveFile");
  if (savedState) {
    const parsedState = JSON.parse(savedState);
    return { tasks: { tasks: parsedState || [] }}; // <-- entire state
  }
  return undefined;
};

const mainStore = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    tasks: itemSlice.reducer,
  },
  preloadedState: loadState(), // <-- entire state
});

mainStore.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(mainStore.getState().tasks); // <-- state.tasks
});



